# HTML decoding in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, html-encode

I have a string that has single and double quotes html encoded - I want to display them in my template decoded (ie as a quote/ single quote). But I *do not* want any other html tags to be decoded.

So for example this string in my db:

```
That is Bob&quot;s dog. &lt;p&gt;
```

Should be presented in my template as:

```
That is Bob's dog &lt;p&gt;
```

Comment: Why are the quotes encoded in the db?  That's only going to cause headaches everywhere.

Comment: @NedBatchelder why will that cause headaches? Isn't it goot security precaution to escape them?

Comment: You're asking why will it cause headaches, but you've come here looking for an answer to a problem caused by the encoding! Your database doesn't need quotes escaped.  It can store "That is Bob's dog <p>" just fine.  You're now in the position of having to interpret a presentation-specific encoding in your server code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to mark it as safe string.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can add a custom filter and use it directly in your template:

```
@register.filter( name='unescape' )
def unescape(val, args):
    return value.decode( 'string-escape' )
unescape.is_safe = True
```

Usage in your template:

```
{{your_string|unescape}}
```

2) Or you could do the same in your view function passing your_string.decode( 'string-escape' ) to your template.

Comment: Telling the truth two quotes will not be decoded as you want by standart function decode( 'string-escape' ). You could add necessary actions to result of function unescape in body of the function unescape.